# How do I get Vue-Cookies to work in Vue-Router Component

Tags: javascript, cookies, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a router index.js file that loads Vue, Vue-Router and Vue-Cookies like so:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies';

Vue.use(Router);
Vue.use(VueCookies);
```

I then define all of my routes like this:

```
const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '*',
      name: 'erorr',
      secure: false,
      component: error404,
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      secure: false,
      component: home,
    },
    {
      path: '/clp',
      name: 'CLP',
      secure: true,
      component: clpHome,
    },
    {
      path: '/saml/login',
      name: 'samlLogin',
      secure: false,
      component: samlLogin,
    },
    {
      path: '/saml/logout',
      name: 'samlLogout',
      secure: false,
      component: samlLogout,
    },
    {
      path: '/user/profile',
      name: 'userProfile',
      secure: false,
      component: userProfile,
    },
  ],
});
```

After this, it is checking to see if a cookie is set:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // Look at all routes
  router.options.routes.forEach((route) => {
    // If this is the current route and it's secure
    if (((to.matched[0].path === route.path || to.matched[0].path === '')/* && route.path === '/'*/) && route.secure) {
      // Check if there's a cookie and verify it
      // Check if user has cookie "SAMLSession"
```

This is where the error pops up, "TypeError: Cannot read property 'isKey' of undefined" When I attempt to 
    console.log(this.$cookies);
it is returned 'undefined' as well.

```
      if (this.$cookies.isKey('SAMLSession')) {
        // Sets the value of "SAMLSession" cookie to a variable
        const sessionId = this.$cookies.get('SAMLSession');
        // Runs function checkSaml located above, then once that completes....
        checkSaml(sessionId).then(result => {
          // Check if the session id is valid via Express, noted by a response of "OK" if good, and "BAD!" if not valid
          if (result.data === 'OK') {
            // If it's good, allow the user to see the page
            next();
          } else {
            // If it's not valid, set a cookie of the page the user was trying to access and then sign them in
            this.$cookies.set('referLocation', to.path, Infinity, '/');
            next('/saml/login');
          }
        });
      } else {
        // If it's not a cookie, set a cookie of the page the user was trying to access and then sign them in
        this.$cookies.set('referLocation', to.path, Infinity, '/');
        next('/saml/login');
      }
    }
  });
  // If nothing has happened, allow the user to visit the page
  next();
});
```

This configuration was working a few days ago, and now it is not loading VueCookies, Any advice in troubleshooting it would be appreciated.

Comment: Your setup looks correct. `this.$cookies` should give your components access to the vue-cookies methods. Maybe your `node_modules` directory was corrupted. Rebuild or build `dist`. You should not have to use `window`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to change all of the 'this.$cookies' objects to 'window.$cookies' like this:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // Look at all routes
  router.options.routes.forEach((route) => {
    // If this is the current route and it's secure
    if (((to.matched[0].path === route.path || to.matched[0].path === '') && route.path === '/') && route.secure) {
      // Check if there's a cookie and verify it
      // Check if user has cookie "SAMLSession"
      if (window.$cookies.isKey('SAMLSession')) {
        // Sets the value of "SAMLSession" cookie to a variable
        const sessionId = window.$cookies.get('SAMLSession');
        // Runs function checkSaml located above, then once that completes....
        checkSaml(sessionId).then(result => {
          // Check if the session id is valid via Express, noted by a response of "OK" if good, and "BAD!" if not valid
          if (result.data === 'OK') {
            // If it's good, allow the user to see the page
            next();
          } else {
            // If it's not valid, set a cookie of the page the user was trying to access and then sign them in
            window.$cookies.set('referLocation', to.path, Infinity, '/');
            next('/saml/login');
          }
        });
      } else {
        // If it's not a cookie, set a cookie of the page the user was trying to access and then sign them in
        window.$cookies.set('referLocation', to.path, Infinity, '/');
        next('/saml/login');
      }
    }
  });
  // If nothing has happened, allow the user to visit the page
  next();
});
```

Comment: using `window` rather than Vue mechanisms seems like a hack.

Comment: The cookie is set by Express and passed on to Vue through `window` in the `next('/saml/login')` endpoint. When the cookie is produced, for authentication, it is done on the back-end, then passed forward and validated on each request.

Comment: yeah, still seems hackish

Comment: Could you recommend where to read this issue in details. Now you told us the hack but why is it that way?

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the same problem, trying to figure why `this` is undefined in router which makes `this.$cookies` error.

Here is how I did it.

```
//add this in the router index.js
import Vue from 'vue'
```

And then, I can access `cookie` variable from `Vue`

```
beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    let access_token = Vue.cookie.get('access_token')
    if (access_token == null) {
        // user doesn't have access token, redirect to login
        next({ name: 'login' })
    }
    else {
        // user has access token, user can open the page
        next()
    }
},
```

Comment: Good to know that the variable changes to `cookie` instead of `$cookie`. I was trying to get `Vue.$cookie` but getting null. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined'
Any idea?

Comment: @SHUJATMUNAWAR there are 2 big plugin for this. vue-cookie and vue-cookies
Try to use it depends on what plugin you are using, Vue.cookie or Vue.$cookies