# Accessing cookies in Vue 3 router Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, cookies

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory, RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router';

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: () => import('../components/LoginComponent.vue'),
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    name: 'register',
    component: () => import('../components/RegisterComponent.vue'),
  },
];

this.$cookies.get('name')

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

object is possibly undefined for `this`
. I have also tried using `this?.$cookies` but then it says `Property $cookies doesn't exist on type never`
What other ways are there to access cookies in the Vue router?

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52736307/6590200

Comment: unfortunately no, i've already tried it, but it says Property 'cookie' does not exist on type 'typeof import("c:/Vue/client/node_modules/vue/dist/vue". Same for the window.$cookies